# ffmpeg retuns different resuslts each run

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm running the following command line on a ubuntu machine:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 md5_fifo.yuv | md5sum md5_fifo.yuv
```

when md5_fifo.yuv is

```
mkfifo md5_fifo.yuv
```

Each run I get different results:

Run 1:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 md5_fifo.yuv | md5sum md5_fifo.yuv
cod0434a2add22a469d7446c7daacffaf74  md5_fifo.yuve here
```

Run 2:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 md5_fifo.yuv | md5sum md5_fifo.yuv
cod2f664c219fb6cac0d416165f3fb5dd23  md5_fifo.yuve here
```

Run 3:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 md5_fifo.yuv | md5sum md5_fifo.yuv
a40598102efed146791322cbf3dd0b2d  md5_fifo.yuv
```

Have anyone encountered this issue??

I've also tried to do it without the pipe and still got different results:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 XXX.yuv:
```

Run 1:

```
md5sum 1.yuv 
f87722d483fc5f85fb2e91686e77c086  1.yuv
```

Run 2:

```
md5sum 2.yuv
d980781a92f1483c83ea6ede336bffd8  2.yuv
```

Run 3:

```
md5sum 3.yuv
8da671589d6b89973ad1b40211d3c3fa  3.yuv
```

**This is the full output of the ffmpeg command:**

[image]

Comment: I had missed the `makefifo` part. You should still use `&&` since `stdout` is empty. Can you also post the full `ffmpeg` console output for one of the runs?

Comment: i've added the full output

Comment: Is the input a large file? This answer says it can be a dying disk: http://serverfault.com/questions/36966/md5sum-repeatedly-gives-different-checksum-for-same-file-on-same-machine

Comment: The inpus is 2.7 MB, the output file is 1.2 GB and I have 60GB free.

Answer (score 0):

You get different results because you're using the commands incorrectly.

Instead of piping the standard output (which is empty anyway in your case) you should use the `&&` operator, meaning the second command will get executed after the first finished and only if it didn't return an error code.

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 run1.yuv -v quiet && md5sum run1.yuv
7f68bbcd0037a5ac4cc0fd396e19d9ba  run1.yuv

ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vsync 0 run2.yuv -v quiet && md5sum run2.yuv
7f68bbcd0037a5ac4cc0fd396e19d9ba  run2.yuv
```

Comment: I've also tried it without fifo and got different results (see bottom part of the question)